# gethostbyname() returns a struct with negative address

Tags: c, gethostbyname

I'm writing a program that would check if a port on given url or ip is open or not. In order to obtain the ip adress of given url, I'm using `gethostbyname()`. When trying to look up the address of localhost it returns the correct value, however, trying to look up the address of a remote host it usually fails and returns an ip address with negative numbers. For example:

```
/test.out google.com
ip: -40.58.-42.78

/test.out reddit.com
ip: -105.101.-127.-116

./test.out facebook.com
ip: 31.13.84.36
```

Weirdly, the last one works. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct hostent *he;
    struct in_addr **addr_list;

    if ((he = gethostbyname(argv[1])) == NULL) {
        herror("gethostbyname");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("ip: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < he->h_length; i++) {
        printf("%d", he->h_addr_list[0][i]);
        if (i != he->h_length - 1) printf(".");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Also, why is the type of `h_addr_list` `char **`? Shouldn't it be an integer, or even better an unsigned one?

Comment: You're probably trying to print strings.

Comment: Use the function `inet_ntoa` to convert the address to a string, rather than coding it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The components of an IP address are unsigned bytes but, in a `struct hostent` they are stored as `char` (i.e. signed). This means the values `128`..`255` are interpreted as negative numbers.

You print them using the `%d` format that prints the values as signed because this is how it receives them. Convert the values to `unsigned char` (or `unsigned int` if you prefer) when you pass them to `printf()`:

```
printf("%d", (unsigned char)he->h_addr_list[0][i]);
```

You can also use `%u` instead of `%d` (it treats as `unsigned` the values it receives), but you still need to convert the values to pass to it to `unsigned`<sup>1</sup>:

```
printf("%u", (unsigned char)he->h_addr_list[0][i]);
```

Another option is to force `printf()` use only the least significant byte of the value it gets and print it as unsigned, using `"%hhu"`. However, this looks more like a hack than the correct solution.

---

<sup>1</sup> Without the conversion, because `printf()` is a [variadic function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic), the values passed to it as arguments (`he->h_addr_list[0][i]`) are promoted from `(signed) char` to `(signed) int`. Using `"%u"` to print them produces very large numbers instead of negative numbers for the components that are larger than `127`.

Comment: The signedness of `char` depends on the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is specifically bout the type of `h_addr_list`.

In the minds of the ancient BSD programmers who invented `gethostbyname`, it was going to be used to look up all kinds of network addresses, not just IP addresses. That's why it also has an `h_addrtype`. The interpretation of `h_addr_list[n]` would be dependent on `h_addrtype`. For `h_addrtype==AF_INET`, an address is the 4-byte IP address format you're familiar with. For other address types, it could be other things.

The `char **` type of `h_addr_list` should be understood as "dynamically allocated array of opaque buffers". It might have been `void **` but `void` hadn't been invented yet.

As it turned out, IPv4 became the only network protocol anyone cared about, until IPv6 came along, and then it was decided to replace the host lookup interface entirely (see `getaddrinfo`). So there have been few opportunities to see a non-`AF_INET` `h_addrtype` in the wild.